# Convergence in mean vs almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, statistics

On this platform, this question is asked many times but I couldn't find a proper answer. The question is, does there exists a counterexample showing convergence in mean does not imply almost sure convergence? Or is it not known yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a sequence of independent rv's $\{Y_n\}$ taking the values $\{0;1\}$ with probability $\left\{1-\frac{1}{n};\frac{1}{n}\right\}$ respectively.

You can see that

$$\lim\limits_{n} \mathbb{E}[Y_n]=\frac{1}{n}=0$$

That means the sequence converges in mean to 0 but applying BC II you get

$$\sum_n\mathbb{P}[|Y_n|>\epsilon]=\sum_n \frac{1}{n}=\infty$$

Thus  the sequence does not converge a.s.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_{k,n} = 1_{[0,{1 \over 2^n}]+\{{k \over 2^n}\}}$ with $k=0,...,n-1$.

Consider the sequence $f_{0,1}, f_{0,2},f_{1,2},f_{0,3},f_{1,3},f_{2,3} ...$, call it $g_m$.

Let the space be $[0,1]$ with the uniform measure.

Note that $E |g_m| \to 0$, but $\limsup_m g_m(x) = 1, \liminf_m g_m(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0,1)$, hence the limit does not exist almost everywhere.